# Replace slash with text in WooCommerce subscription

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

how to replace the slash in WooCommerce subscription product price string with text?
Currently, the subscription displays the following price string:
"€60.00 / month for 6 months"

I want to change it to:
""€60.00 **per** month for 6 months"

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string', 'woocommerce_subscription_price_string', 10, 3);
function woocommerce_subscription_price_string($subscription_string, $product, $include){

    $subscription_string = str_replace(' / ', 'per ', $subscription_string);
    return $subscription_string;
    
}
```